# mysql How to Find Difference between two rows in same table and list the Unmatched Records? mysql finding unmatched rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL i want to find difference between the two rows in same table 
where i need to display the unmatched records

Here is my Table named `project_details`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_details` (
  `project_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `project_detail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `project_version` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `project_details` (`project_name`, `project_detail`, `project_version`) VALUES
('project_1', 'php_mysql', '1.0'),
('project_1', 'php_mysql_android', '2.0'),
('project_1', 'php_mysql_android_ajax', '3.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql', '1.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_android', '2.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_android_ajax', '3.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_jquery', '1.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql', '4.0');
```

This is how table looks like

[image]

where i want the result of unmatched records from the table 
that is from comparing project_1 and project_2

need to Compare both project_1 and project_2 from project_name then it should get the unmatched records of project_detail and project_version

i need result something like this displaying only unmatched records refer below 
pic

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to retrieve output where for different project names there are no matching rows based on detail and version:

```
select *
from project_details p1
where not exists (
  select 1
  from project_details p2
  where p1.project_name <> p2.project_name
    and p1.project_detail = p2.project_detail
    and p1.project_version = p2.project_version
  )
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48aa7/1)** to see how it works live.

**Output**

```
project_name    project_detail      project_version
---------------------------------------------------
project_2       php_mysql_jquery    1.0
project_2       php_mysql           4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 select pd1.* from project_details as pd1 
     left join project_details as pd2 
     on (
       pd1.project_detail=pd2.project_detail and 
       pd1.project_version=pd2.project_version and
       pd1.project_name<>pd2.project_name)
     where pd2.project_name is null
```

Comment: You want to join only  rows with different project names.