# mysql find the difference between two rows in same table and display only the second row difference not the first row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_details` (
  `project_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `project_detail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `project_version` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `project_details` (`project_name`, `project_detail`, `project_version`) VALUES
('project_1', 'php_mysql', '1.0'),
('project_1', 'php_mysql_android', '2.0'),
('project_1', 'php_mysql_android_ajax', '3.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql', '1.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_android', '2.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_android_ajax', '3.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_jquery', '1.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql', '4.0');
```

This is how table looks like

[image]

where by comparing both rows in a same table with query below

```
select *
from project_details p1
where not exists (
select 1
from project_details p2
where p1.project_name <> p2.project_name
and p1.project_detail = p2.project_detail
and p1.project_version = p2.project_version
)
```

successfully iam getting the output difference of project_1 and project_2 some thing like this

[image]

now if i change the records in the table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_details` (
  `project_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `project_detail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `project_version` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `project_details` (`project_name`, `project_detail`, `project_version`) VALUES
('project_1', 'php_mysql', '1.0'),
('project_1', 'php_mysql_android', '2.0'),
('project_1', 'php_mysql_android_ajaxs', '4.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql', '1.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_android', '2.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_android_ajax', '3.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql_jquery', '1.0'),
('project_2', 'php_mysql', '4.0');
```

where records changed table looks like this

[image]

with the same comparing query like above ,comparing project_1 and project_2  iam able to get output like this

[image]

but here i want to display only project_2 difference alone. i dont want show project_1 difference

more simply : i want to compare both the rows of project_1 and project_2 but i want to display only project_2 difference alone no need to display project_1 difference information

```
That is I need to show some thing like comparing with project_1 what all are difference found in project_2
```

i need query for this , thanks in advance

Comment: I've [answered your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39186813/mysql-how-to-find-difference-between-two-rows-in-same-table-and-list-the-unmatch). The reason this is happening is because `project_detail` is different for project 1 and 2. They are completely different rows and so there is no match.

Comment: ya ,,, if match is there in 1 st row i dont want to display it ,                            that is compare both rows but display project_2 information only

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. They are both __different__ so we display both of them.

Comment: is there a possibility to display only project_2 information alone by compare both rows

Comment: i understood both are different and if i change records it will  display both of them ..   i need to accomplish something like , for example i want to compare both rows where i need display only project_2 . ,, in my project project_1 row will be like master and project_2 will be like delta .. so from comparing with project_1 i want to show what all values are changed  on project_2

Comment: Like Kamil G., I'm trying to understand. Do you want to both 1) print the project_2 data and 2) show which of the data has changed from project_1?

Comment: yes ,,, your  partially correct i hope this explanation could give you hint what iam asking...... see now by using kamil G query we will get difference of both project_1 and project_2 ,,,                                                           what i need is from project_1 show which of the data is changed in project_2  .. this is what i need.

Comment: i want to display project_2 data which has changes from project_1

Comment: I want to display project_2 datas alone which is diffrent from project _1

Comment: "but here i want to display only project_2 difference alone. i dont want show project_1 difference". This is just an additional condition: `p1.project_name = 'project_2'` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/035126/4

Comment: this is what I need thanks so much

Comment: Yup I was going the same direction: I thought he could substitute "where p1.project_name <> p2.project_name" with "where p1.project_name = 'project_2' and p2.project_name = 'project_2'". The two conditions in my answer guarantee the inequality in his condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is just an additional condition:

```sql
p1.project_name = 'project_2'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/035126/4

But you can do it better and select all version differences between 'project_1' and 'project_2':

```sql
select pd.project_detail, 
  p1.project_version as old_version,
  p2.project_version as new_version
from(
  select distinct project_detail
  from project_details
  where project_name in ('project_1', 'project_2')
) pd
left join project_details p1
  on  p1.project_name = 'project_1'
  and p1.project_detail = pd.project_detail
left join project_details p2
  on  p2.project_name = 'project_2'
  and p2.project_detail = pd.project_detail
where not (p1.project_version <=> p2.project_version)
```

The result will be something like:

```sql
|         project_detail | old_version | new_version |
|------------------------|-------------|-------------|
| php_mysql_android_ajax |         4.0 |         3.0 |
|              php_mysql |         1.0 |         4.0 |
|    somthing_depricated |         1.0 |      (null) |
|       php_mysql_jquery |      (null) |         1.0 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9005c/1

Comment: in this case : p1.project_name = 'project_2' is absouletly working     say for example iam taking both the project names in a data set or combo box or drop down box )                     input 1 as ->project_1 and input 2 as -> project_2  then condition p1.project_name = 'project_2'   will work fine                        if i have more number of projects like project_3,project_4,project_5  and iam taking this in data set or drop down and if i have a view button and click on it   it should display difference in that case p1.project_name = 'project_2' what condition should be added?

Comment: @SanjaiKummar - The problem with the first solution, ist that you will not see, which technologies has been dropped. In the example table 'somthing_depricated' has been used in 'project_1' but not in 'project_2'. This in my opinion is a change - but it won't be shown with the first solution. ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9005c/4))